# Consume Azure SQL Database with Android?

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, rest, azure-sql-database

currently I am working on developing an Android application which will pull data from an Azure SQL Database.  I am just curious on what would be suggested as the best way for Android to interact with the database.  Currently, I am thinking of using a WCF RESTful Service.

The reason I am asking is I just would like to be sure this would be one of the best approaches to solve this problem and that there is not another way I potentially could have looked over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but it may help others who might be thinking to connect Android apps to SQL Azure database. Microsoft has a official Android SDK and support for Mobile Services. You can check this [Get started with Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-android-get-started/).
It has got loads of examples and tutorials which would definitely help anyone who is starting with Android and SQL Azure.